# Why cant i store 20 kilibytes image in mysql

Tags: mysql, .net, blob, mysql-connector

I am storing thumbnail size images (less that 50kb) in `tinyblob` field in mysql using the MysqlConnector for .net using the following code

```
Dim imgCov As New ImageConverter()
        Dim imgArray As Byte() = DirectCast(imgCov.ConvertTo(pictureBox1.Image , GetType(Byte())), Byte())

        Try
            Using conn As New MySqlConnection(conStr)
                conn.Open
                Dim sql As String ="Insert Into Services(Name,Code,Emp_ID,Image) Values(@Name,@Code,@Emp_ID,@Image)"
                Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql,conn)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value ="Ironing"
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Code", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value ="IRN"
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Emp_ID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value =1
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", MySqlDbType.LongBlob, 100).Value=imgArray
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ()
                End Using
            End Using
            MsgBox("Insert Complete")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

The problem is when i store the image, it doesn't save all the data. This is apparent when i tried retrieving and i started getting errors.

Investigating the errors, i simple increased the field size to `longblob` which there after worked fine.

So why cant i store a 20KB image in tinyblob field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TINYBLOB can only hold 256 Bytes; you need at least a regular BLOB, which can store 64KB.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html